# Can I Refer to "the $k$th Term" in a Permutation $\sigma$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations, terminology

Since permutations may be regarded as sequences, I would like to be able to refer to the $k$th term in a permutation without having to explicitly state that I am referring to a member of a sequence. I would like to be able to say, for example: "The third term in the permutation $\sigma = (2,1,4,3, \ldots, 2j,2j-1, \ldots)$ is $4$."

Is this permitted?

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach, given that permutations can be expressed a number of ways (including factors).  Personally, I'd say merely "$3$ goes to $4$," or "the target of $3$ is $4$," or equivalent.

Comment: There are at least two different notations for permutations, the one line notation and the cycle notation https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation

Comment: I'd simply write $\sigma(3)=4$.

Comment: How about if I define a sequence to be a given permutation and then refer to terms in the sequence?  I'm thinking of something along the lines of: "Let the sequence $\sigma = (\sigma(p_{1}), \sigma(p_{2}), \sigma(p_{3}), \ldots)$ be a permutation of $(p_{1}, p_{2}, p_{3}, \ldots)$, where $p_{k}$ is the $k$th prime number.  Then $\sigma_{4}$ is obviously a prime number, and..."